# Allow Lead conversion only when Lead Status is Qualified

Tags: lead-conversion

On the Lead object, in the Status field I have following values

Open (default)

Unqualified

Qualified (Converted)

Initial Conversation

Specs Sent

Approval Received

I want the user to be able to convert the Lead to an Account, Contact and Opportunity only if the Status = Qualified

**My Approach**

Create a checkbox 'Qualified__c' and set it to True via process builder when Status = 'Qualified'
then, use the validation rule to prevent the Lead from being converted.

Is there a better approach than mine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they convert the Lead, they will need to select Qualified as the new Lead Status. Further, they won't be able to set the status to Qualified *until* the Lead is converted. There's no need for such a validation.